# Plot multiple y-axis and colors but a single x-axis

Tags: python, plotly, legend, plotly-python, multiple-axes

I'm trying to plot 4 types of data on a single graph using plotly.
they all share the x-axis but one of them has a different y-axis to it,
I want to plot the first few categories which share the x and y axis with different colors by category
and a legend to match.
and to plot the other data which has a different y axis on the same x axis as the previous data

I put together a simplified example of what I'm trying to do
the Dataframe is  like in the picture below and the code is my unsuccessful attempt of plotting.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,np.nan],"B":[np.nan,1],'frq':[10,20]})
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index ,y=df['A']),secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index ,y=df['B']),secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index ,y=df['frq']),secondary_y=True)
fig.show()
px.bar(df).show()
```

The out come is as follows

[image]

I get a mess with sparse x axis sloths

using plotly.express I can easily plot the bar plot and get a decent graph(Down below ) but then it's problematic to add another y-axis for the other type of data

[image]

The desired outcome is something like this

[image]

I tried to look using pd.melt() to combine the sparse data and then to color it but then the legend becomes a problem.

I have found the solution evidently i had some Nan values or 0 values in the plotted data frame using the script bellow worked

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for column in colmns_list:
    f=df[[column]]
    f=f[f>0].dropna()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=f.index, y=f[column], name=column,),
        secondary_y=False
    )
```

Comment: can you clarify what the desired outcome is? is the problem in the first chart that the scatter isn't centered on the bars?

Comment: First, you should post only one problem per question. When your first question is solved, add your second one. But here I think you have 3 problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution evidently i had some Nan values or 0 values in the plotted data frame using the script bellow worked

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for column in colmns_list:
    f=df[[column]]
    f=f[f>0].dropna()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=f.index, y=f[column], name=column,),
        secondary_y=False
    )
```